# TabBar Controller with custom action

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am new to swift. I am implementing tabbar controller in my Project and facing some design difficulty. My goal is when user click a tabbar item it should not navigate to another view controller. It should stayed in the current view and add a pop up view to the current view controller.I have tried but always it navigate to next view controller.

Comment: You can't achieve this through a `UITabBarController`.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `UITabBarController` subclass and use that class for your tab bar controller. Confirm to `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in the tab bar controller and return false in `tabBarController shouldSelect` method when you don't want to navigate to a view controller. Here you can show the popup view.

```
class TabbarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController,
            navigationController.viewControllers.contains(where: { $0 is MoreViewController }) {
            //show pop up view
            return false
        } else  {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can add `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in one of its embedded view controller like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
    }
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController,
            navigationController.viewControllers.contains(where: { $0 is MoreViewController }) {
            //show pop up view
            return false
        } else  {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am using navigation controller as a root view. since it returning only true. can u plz update the code for navigation controller in shouldSelect delegate.